# c# asp.net como insertar imagenes a un excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Tengo que un excel y en la posición B1 hay un tag que denomina FIRMA_TRABAJADOR.
Como se podría cargar un imagen usando c#(asp.net) a la posición del tag?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver asp.net con una columna de excel? ¿Que has intentado? ¿Que estas haciendo y de donde sale ese excel? Hay muchas incógnitas, te recomiendo que te hagas el [tour]

Comment: Hola @Jay Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Por favor intenta incluir un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has intentado, que nos ayude a entender mejor tu problema. Te invito a revisar las recomendaciones en [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)